# Why is 10 not a Kaprekar Number?

Tags: number-theory

I am stuck in this hackerrank problem where it asks to output [Kaprekar numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number), and since $10^2 = 100$, and it can be represented as $10+0$, where could I be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number

Quoting,

"By convention, the second part may start with the digit 0, but must be nonzero."

Comment: Would you mind changing the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number
instead of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number?

Comment: @MXYMXY Done. (more characters)

Comment: Drat, you beat me to it :-) .